# How can i permanently save a change in the column type when dealing with a new dynamic dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, dynamic

I am trying to do what this script shows

```
DF_Data$`Date [MM/DD/YY]`<-    as.Date( get(paste(x,"_Data",sep=""))$`Date [MM/DD/YY]` )
```

however the DF_Date name is not meant to be static so ideally i would like to accomplish something like this

```
get(paste(x,"_Data",sep=""))$`Date [MM/DD/YY]`<- as.Date( get(paste(x,"_Data",sep=""))$`Date [MM/DD/YY]` )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, we may need `assign` instead of `get`

```
x <- "DF"
obj_nm <- paste0(x, '_Data')
assign(obj_nm, `[<-`(get(obj_nm), "Date [MM/DD/YY]",
     value = as.Date(get(obj_nm)[['Date [MM/DD/YY]']])))
```

-checking

```
str(DF_Data)
#'data.frame':  2 obs. of  2 variables:
#$ Date [MM/DD/YY]: Date, format: "2015-10-25" "2018-05-26"
#$ val            : num  -0.546 0.537
```

#### data

```
set.seed(24)
DF_Data <- data.frame(`Date [MM/DD/YY]` = c("2015-10-25", "2018-05-26"),
             val = rnorm(2), check.names = FALSE)
```

Comment: I added two more right parenthesis and got subscript out of bounds. I'll continue playing with it and see what happens.

Comment: @user35131 i created a small reproducible example which is working fine with the code.  In my earlier version, I missed a `)`.  Now, it is corrected.

Comment: assign(paste(x,"_Data",sep=""), `[<-`(get(paste(x,"_Data",sep="")), "`Date [MM/DD/YY]`",
                     value = as.Date(get(paste(x,"_Date",sep=""))[['`Date [MM/DD/YY]`']])))

I got this and though it ran my column was still character. Know if doing anything wrong here. I didn't set the variables like you but i believe this is ok.

Comment: @user35131 can you please update your post with that code as it is difficult to know from the comments as the backquotes are removed

Comment: @user35131 i updated the example. please check.  it is working fine for me